# Pass URL query string parameters from page to iFrame in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, iframe, parameters

I have a Wordpress page on `http://example.com/demo`. If I attach some URL query string parameters, like `http://example.com/demo?param1=123&param2=456`, I get a 404 error on Wordpress. I need those params only to put them on an iFrame URL, I don't need to do anything with them inside Wordpress. Do you have any ideas on how I can pass them?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an 404 error because of your permalink structure. You need to save the permalinks as `post name` instead of `plain`. To change the permalinks : Go to `Settings->Permalinks->Change to post name->Save`

After than you can pass the variables to the URL as `GET` parameters.

Comment: Actually I already have my Permalink set to Post name, I believe that's the reason why I get 404 when adding the params